# Code coverage Missed instructions on testing exceptions

Tags: java, code-coverage

```
   @Test
   public void testNullPointerException() {
      thrown = false;
      IntList list = null;
      IntList sublist = new IntList(null);
      IntList newList = new IntList(2, 2, 4);
      try {
         actual = OrderedIntListUtility.replaceAll(list, sublist, newList);
      } catch(NullPointerException e) {
         thrown = true;
      }
   }
```

Java code coverage tells that I have some missed instructions in this particular test. I don't know where are the missed instructions here. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I would worry less about missed instructions, and more about correctness if I were you. Your test will succeed whether or not a NullPointerException is thrown. That said, you didn't even posted the code under test, so how could we know which instructions could be missed?

Answer (score 2):

From eclemma documentation - http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html

```
Instructions (C0 Coverage) - The smallest unit JaCoCo counts are single Java byte code instructions. Instruction coverage   
provides information about the amount of code that has been executed or missed. This metric is 
completely independent from source formatting and always available, even in absence of debug 
information in the class files.
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with this:
Code with exceptions shows no coverage. Why?

"JaCoCo determines code execution with so called probes. Probes are inserted into the control flow at certain positions. Code is considered as executed when a subsequent probe has been executed. In case of exceptions such a sequence of instructions is aborted somewhere in the middle and not marked as executed."

http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html

Thanks, btw!